# Why do game theorists use a discounted payoff of this form?

Tags: game-theory, dynamic-programming, optimal-control, bellman-equations, discount

Excuse the click-baity title. I notice the discounted payoff in the game theory literature usually takes the form

$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty\lambda(1-\lambda)^{t-1}R_t$$

This differs from the discounted payoff in the other dynamic optimization settings, e.g., see the [Bellman equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation) in control theory.

Why the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, it's mainly just for cleanliness for results.

Consider an infinite horizon repeated game, with discounted payoff representation (where I use $\delta = (1-\lambda)$ in your notation)
$$
(1-\delta)\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\delta^t R_t
$$
where $0 < \delta < 1$.

Suppose I play a strategy that gives me the same payoff, say $a$, for each period $t$. Then,
$$
(1-\delta)\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\delta^t a = (1-\delta)\frac{a}{1-\delta} = a
$$
which is cleaner than
$$
\frac{a}{1-\delta}
$$
As a side note, multiplying the utility by a constant does not change preferences, so we keep the inherent preferences the same.

Comment: In fact, arguably utility should be considered an equivalence class, and a particular formula simply an representative of that class. Two formulas in the same equivalence class are essentially the same utility.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to repeated games, in which player $i$ obtains a payoff of the form $$(1-\delta)\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\delta^{t}u_{i}(x_{i}^{t})$$

from the sequence of payoffs $\left\{x_{i}^{t}\right\}$? The $(1-\delta)$ is appended to the front to give the *average* per period payoff.